# Photo in windows preview show as portrait but in photoshop or msword show as landscape

Tags: photoshop, preview

I have a photo provided by one of my customer. 
When I preview that photo in window's preview it shows as Portrait, which is fine.

But when I import/open same photo in Photoshop or Microsoft Word it opens as Landscape(side ways). Why?

Anybody come across this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orientation info in the EXIF data of the photo is possibly incorrect (either due to some post-processing, or the software used to save it not setting it correctly, or it's not been set correctly in-camera - happened to me before in specific angles). The file says it is landscape although the picture is portrait.

The integrated image viewer does not take it into account (at least on my OS version) so displays it as portrait, but other programs take it into account therefore displaying it (correctly from their point of view) in landscape.

You can simply rotate the image or attempt to fix the EXIF data.

Answer (score 0):

So the camera got the orientation wrong (happens sometimes) but some programs will automatically figure it out and others wont, sometimes by design (photoshop wont).

To fix the orientation, just open it in your favorite image editor, rotate it as you like, and save at the highest quality. Next time it will open with the right orientation in every program.

Comment: Instead of resaving at highest quality, use a specialized tool to change the orientation flag without rewriting the data, or to do lossless jpeg rotation (yes, that's a thing).